# Can't use mongo commands in console anymore

Tags: meteor

I used to be able to use the Chrome Tools Console to type in Mongo commands on my Meteor app and see the results.  Stuff like, Collection.findOne({name: "foo"}).  It is also done this way in the tutorials on the Meteor site.

Now, for any mongo commands, I just get [collection] not defined.  It makes debugging MUCH more difficult.

Perhaps something changed in the last few releases?  Any insights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Meteor 0.6.0 individual files are variable scoped. So if you have a collection defined via

```
var Collection = new Meteor.Collection("collection");
```

It won't be visible on the console anymore (but it will be visible in the file its defined in)

The workaround is to define the file globally which is just removing the `var`:

```
Collection = new Meteor.Collection("collection");
```

Then you should be able to access it on the chrome js console once again

Comment: Thanks Akshat.  To future coffeescript readers, use the @ symbol as follows: @Collection = new Meteor.Collection("collection")